# typemap rule is confusing

Tags: types, mpi, standards

According to MPI 2.2 standard Section 4.1: to create a new data type we have to define a typemap which is a sequence of (type, displacement) pairs. The displacements *are not required* to be positive, increasing, nor distinct.

- Suppose I define a typemap of the following sequence: {(double, 0), (char,0)} this does not make sense, yet possible, how can a standard provide so much flexibility?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? That is, did you successfully define and commit such a datatype on some MPI implementation?

Comment: Probably MPI implementations will not allow it, I just wonder what exactly is the idea behind this freedom offered by the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only thing you find confusing about typemaps, you're smarter than I am.   But as to this particular example -- C unions are exactly this; why shouldn't typemaps allow it?

Comment: You are right. so do you think the reason behind this is merely to save memory? or perhaps define a Swiss-army knife typemap for all messages?

Comment: My guess is that it's two things: One is implementatibility; they didn't want to force MPI implementers to do a big suite of tests on the typemaps at commit time.  The other is just flexibility; when creating a standard (especially on a wide range of machines; in the 80s when this was being put together there were a dizzying variety of architechtures out there) it's hard to know who will find what useful, so best just to let everything be ok and if people shoot themselves in the foot, so be it -- this is HPC after all.  I still don't understand the legality of *negative* displacements, but...

Answer (score 1):

I started writing a comment but ran out of space, so here goes. First off, this code compiles and runs on the HP-MPI implmentation that I have access to:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int count = 2;
  int lengths[] = { 1, 1 };
  MPI_Aint disp[] = { 0, 0 };
  MPI_Datatype types[] = { MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_CHAR };
  MPI_Datatype weird_type;

  MPI_Type_struct(count, lengths, disp, types, &weird_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&weird_type);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

However, the `{ (double, 0), (char,0) }` typemap won't behave like a union: if you send data with this typemap, the same memory address will first be interpreted as a `double`, then as a `char`, and both values will be sent (assuming the implementation doesn't implode).

I can only think of one plausible use case for this sort of behavior: consider the typemap `{ (MPI_CHAR, 0), (MPI_BYTE,0) }`. Sending a `char` variable using this type will perform representation conversion in the first case, but not in the second: this way, you can check if the character encoding is the same on the sender and receiver machine. Of course there are other ways to do this, but still, the option's there. Though the more likely scenario is that the standard simply doesn't concern itself with exotic special cases.

Also, regarding negative displacements: I actually used these before when I had to pass data from a linked data structure (e.g. a graph). This is not for the faint of heart, but here's the pseudocode of my algorithm:

```
std::vector<MPI_Aint> displacements;
for (each node n in the graph)
{
    if ( n needs to be sent )
    {
        displacements.push_back(<MPI address of n>);
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<displacements.size(); i++)
{
    // compute the element #i's offset from the first one
    displacements[i] -= displacements[0];
}

// create HIndexed datatype where blocks consist of one node,
// and begin at the memory addresses in 'displacements'

// send nodes as one element of the previously defined type,
// beginning at the address of the first node
```

Hopefully you can see the importance of negative displacements from there: there's no telling where the various nodes are in memory, so it's entirely possible that some nodes will be at earlier locations than the one at which we begin traversing the graph.

Comment: Huh, that's all really interesting.   I guess I never thought of actually sending bits of a linked data structure with a MPI datatype; I always just figured that such a structure would be too dynamic to bother creating types and one would just send the nodes individually.    Re the typemaps, you must be right about the send, but the receive (with the same typemap) would end up folding them back into the same 8 bytes and so you would end up with the union-type approach, I'd think -- I'm curious to try (and even more curious to know if different MPIs actually implement this the same way).

Comment: Well, do keep in mind that the datatype above goes out of date when the datastructure changes, so you likely have to redefine/recommit it before every send, which has its own cost. Also keep in mind that you can receive a message using a different typemap than it was sent with: receiving with `{ (MPI_CHAR, 0), (MPI_BYTE,4) }` will store the two values separately.