# send glib hashtable with MPI

Tags: c, hashtable, mpi, glib

i recently came across a problem with my parallel program. Each process has several glib hashtables that need to be exchanged with other processes, these hashtables may be quite large. What is the best approach to achieve that?

- create derived datatype
- use mpi pack and unpack
- send key & value as arrays (problem, since amount of elements is not known at compile time)

I haven't used 1 & 2 before and don't even know if thats possible, that's why i am asking you guys..

Comment: You might also want to investigate single-sided memory access, as implemented in MPI-2.  I stress the word 'might'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack/unpack creates a copy of your data: if your maps are large, you'll want to avoid that. This also rules out your 3rd option.

You can indeed define a custom datatype, but it'll be a little tricky. See the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330074/typemap-rule-is-confusing) for an example (replacing "graph" with "map" and "node" with "pair" as you read). I suggest you [read up](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node70.html#SECTION00400000000000000000) on these topics to get a firm understanding of what you need to do.

That the number of elements is not known at compile time shouldn't be a real issue. You can just send a message containing the payload size before sending the map contents. This will let the receiving process allocate just enough memory for the receive buffer.

You may also want to consider simply printing the contents of your maps to files, and then having the processes read each others' ouput. This is much more straightforward, but also less elegant and much slower than message passing.